# What is the use of Spectral Theorem?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, operator-theory, spectral-theory, operator-algebras

Obviously the version for compact and self-adjoint linear operators on Hilbert Spaces is very useful since it decomposes the operators into orthogonal projections.

However, the following more general version for commutative $C^*$ subalgebras of $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ do not seem so handy to me.

Let $\mathcal{A}\in\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ be a $C^*$ subalgebra containing $I$ and $\Sigma$ be its spectrum. Then for $u,v\in \mathcal{H}$, $f\mapsto \langle T_f u,v\rangle$ is a bounded linear functional on $C(\Sigma)$, where $T_f$ is the operator mapped to $f$ by Gelfand transformation, hence defines a measure $\mu_{u,v}$ on $\Sigma$.

Then there is a regular projection-valued measure $P$ on $\Sigma$ such that $T=\int \hat{T}dP$  for all $T\in\mathcal{A}$ and $T_{f}=\int fdP$ for all $f\in B(\Sigma)$, where $\hat{T}$ is the Gelfand transformation of $T$ and $T_{f}$ is defined by $\langle T_{f}u,v\rangle=\int fd\mu_{u,v}$. Moreover, if $S\in\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$, the followings are equivalent:

i.$S$ commutes with every $T\in\mathcal{A}$.

ii. $S$ commmutes with $P(E)$ for every Borel $E$

iii. $S$ commutes with $\int f dP$ for every $f\in B(\Sigma)$.

Although it is also somewhat decomposition, but they involve integrals and regular measures that *exist*, but are not constructed in a step-by-step fashion like in the simpler version and about which we do not actually know much.

Thus I wonder how useful this theorem is and it would be great if some examples can be provided.

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12547/what-is-the-spectral-theorem-for-compact-self-adjoint-operators-on-a-hilbert-spa

Comment: Useful in what sense? Proving theorems? Gaining insight? Constructing aircraft?

Comment: I'm going to go against a recent trend and remove the Banach algebras tag, because this question is very specific to the setting of subalgebras of $B(H)$.

Comment: @YemonChoi hi, Yemon! By usefulness I mean both proving theorems and gaining insights. I know some examples of how this spectral theorem might be used to prove things yet they do not seem deserve such a big theorem. Also, concerning the theorem you mentioned in your answer, I think mine is more general than the version in rudin and takes much more effort to prove. So my question is: why bother to prove this generalized version?

Comment: I am not convinced that what you have written is *really* more general than that in Rudin. I see that it applies to commutative C*-subalgebras whereas Rudin probably restricts attention to subalgebras generated by a single normal element, but the underlying principles are the same, if I recall correctly

Comment: As for "why bother to prove this generalized version" - it tells you that the same projection-valued measure works for every element in your algebra, so you now have *joint* functional calculus for a *set* of commuting normal operators.

Comment: An afterthought: representation theorems like this might not always have "uses" in the sense you seem to want. What they do is allow us to transport our understanding of one setting (in this case, functions and measures) to another setting (subalgebras of $B(H)$). The more complete our "dictionary", the better chance we have of making progress when doing research, because we have more ways of looking at the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

What you describe is more or less the spectral theorem for normal operators on Hilbert space, which in turn yields the Borel functional calculus for such operators. See Chapter 12 of Rudin's *Functional Analysis* (2nd ed.), in particular 12.21-12.24.

As to why to Borel FC might be useful: well, it gives us a way of using what we know about bounded measurable functions to prove and construct things about (normal) operators on Hilbert space. For instance, the polar decomposition of a bounded operator $T$ on Hilbert space can only be proved, as far as I know, by using Borel functional calculus for the operator $T^*T$. In turn, the polar decomposition gives probably the quickest way to show that the unitary group of $B(H)$ is connected in the norm topology.

Note also that if $T$ is normal and belongs to a von Neumann algebra $M\subseteq B(H)$, then so does $f(T)$ for $f$ a bounded Borel function on $\sigma(T)$. So the functional calculus is - and needs to be - used when developing the structure theory of von Neumann algebras, because it allows us to construct elements with prescribed properties that still lie inside the specified von Neumann algebra.

Comment: Existence and uniqueness of the polar decomposition can be proved by hand by applying a suitable sequence of polynomials to $T^\ast T$ and using some facts on partial isometries that follow from Bessel and polarization. This is done in chapter 3.2 of Pedersen's *Analysis Now*, for example. This doesn't really detract from your point of course, but in that argument there's no spectral theory entering.

Comment: How does the polar decomposition quickly show that the unitary group of $B(H)$ is connected in the norm topology?

Answer (score 0):

I like the application where one uses the spectral theorem to show that any irreducible unitary representation of an abelian group $G$, $\pi:G\to U(H)$, must be $1$ dimensional. I guess you would look at the spectrum of any fixed $\pi(x_0)$ and argue that if it had more than one point, you could use $P$ to find non-trivial projections which commute with every $\pi(x)$ (thus giving invariant subspaces). This last part uses the equivalence stated in the theorem.
I don't know how to prove this without using the spectral theorem.

Also, the $L^2$-ergodic theorem has a neat proof using spectral theory. You can show $\frac{1}{n}(x+Ux+\dots U^{n-1}x)$ converges by looking at it as an integral on the spectrum of $U$ and using the dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was thinking about the polar decomposition on the group $G= \operatorname{SU}(2,2)$ which is given by the closed subset:
\begin{equation}
G = \left\lbrace g \in \operatorname{GL}(4,\mathbb{C}): \det g =1, gJg* = g\right\rbrace \ \text{ where }\ J = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   I_2 & 0 \\
   0 & -I_2 
  \end{array} } \right].
\end{equation}
Let $\mathfrak{g}$ denote the Lie algebra of $G$.
In the following proof, I found it very convenient to use the **uniqueness statements involved in the functional calculus of the spectral theorem**.

**Proposition:** For each $g \in G$, there exist unique $k \in \operatorname{U}(4)\cap G$ and $p \in \mathfrak{g}$ with $p^* =p$ such that $g = k \exp(p)$.

**Proof:** Note that $G$ is closed under conjugations: If we have $gJg^* = J$, then $JgJg^* = I_4$ so that $(g^*)^{-1} = JgJ$. Thus $g^* J g = J$.

Now take $g \in G$ and consider the (strictly) positive element $h = g^* g \in G$. ((Strictly positive) positive means that the spectrum is contained in the (positive reals) non-negative reals.) The spectral theorem (or standard linear algebra) gives a hermitian element $p \in \operatorname{Mat}_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{C})$ with
\begin{equation}
h = \exp (p).
\end{equation}
In particular $p^* = p$ and $\operatorname{Trace}(p) = 0$. Although we don't know at this point whether $p \in \mathfrak{g}$. Consider the one-parameter subgroup
\begin{equation}
\exp(rp) \in \operatorname{GL}(4,\mathbb{C}) \text{ where } r \in \mathbb{R}.
\end{equation}
Note that, since $hJh = J$, we have
\begin{equation}
h = J h^{-1} J. \text{ That is, } \exp(p) = J \exp(-p) J.
\end{equation}
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and consider the positive elements
\begin{equation}
 \exp\left(\frac{1}{n}p\right)\ \text{ and }\ J \exp\left(\frac{-1}{n}p\right) J.
\end{equation}
Both of these elements satisfy $(\star)^n = h$.

Now, the spectral theorem (functional calculus) actually says that if we have two positive matrices in $\operatorname{Mat}_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{C})$ whose $n$th powers are the same, then they must be the same matrix!

Thus, for every $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have
\begin{equation}
\exp\left(\frac{m}{n} p\right) = J \exp \left(\frac{-m}{n} p\right) J.
\end{equation}
By continuity we have, for all $r \in \mathbb{R}$,
\begin{equation}
\exp(rp) = J \exp(-rp) J \text{ or that } \exp(rp) J \exp(rp) = J.
\end{equation}
Thus, $p \in \mathfrak{g}$. We define $k = g \exp(-p/2) \in G$ and compute
\begin{equation}
k^*k = \exp(-p/2) g^* g \exp (-p/2) = \exp(-p/2) \exp(p) \exp(-p/2) = I_4.
\end{equation}
Thus, $g = k \exp(p/2)$ is the required decomposition. The uniqueness part of the polar decomposition uses the same principle about uniqueness of positive square roots of a matrix.